# Populating APEX Maps with object ID's as keys and object names as values

Tags: apex, map, id

The invoices.get( ... ) in the last line returns null because the invoices keySet contains keys which are not Opportunity__c.Id's like I expected. I am doing something like this in the following execute anonymous code:

```
Id key = '006G000000TZ2f9IAD';
Map<Id, Invoice1__c> invoices = new Map<Id, Invoice1__c> ([SELECT Opportunity__c
                                                                , Name
                                                            FROM Invoice1__c
                                                            WHERE Opportunity__c = :key]);

system.debug('Created Map. Number of Invoice names mapped=' + invoices.size());
system.debug('Invoices.Get=' + invoices.get(key));
```

I would like to be able to pull the Invoice1__c.Name from the Map something like:

`String invoiceName = invoices.get(newTicket.sbx_Opportunity__c).Name;`

1. How do I properly populate a `Map` of `<OpportunityID, Invoice1__c.Name>`. Like this
   `<006G000000TZ2f9IAD, 'Inv-0561'>`
2. What are the Id's that I currently see in the invoices variable keySet?

Answer (score 4):

This construction

```
Map<Id, Invoice1__c> invoices = new Map<Id, Invoice1__c> ([query]);
```

always return Map that contains object Id as a key and Object as a value.
When I said "Object" I mean object about you query, so you can't expect that this construction will put lookup value as key.

In your case you have to construct map in for loop

Try

```
Map<Id, Invoice1__c[]> invoices = new Map<Id, Invoice1__c[]>();


for(Invoice1__c inv : [SELECT Opportunity__c, Name, Id
                       FROM Invoice1__c
                       WHERE Opportunity__c = :key]){
    if(!invoices.containsKey(inv.Opportunity__c)){    
        invoices.put(inv.Opportunity__c, new Invoice1__c[]{});
    }
    invoices.get(inv.Opportunity__c).add(inv);
}
```

I've changed Invoice1_*c to list of Invoice1*_c because as I can see it is child of Opportunity and there is risk that one opportunity can have many Invoice1__c. 
Also I think it is better to have object in map than just name.

Comment: You can save a script statement by creating the new list with the first record already in it.

Answer (score 2):

The key in your map is the `invoice1__c` id value, since you're executing the query against that object and creating a map from those results.

In order to create a map with a different structure than `Map<Id, sObject>`, you need to create that structure yourself.

Your question's code shows a 1-to-many relationship between `opportunity` and `invoice1__c` and I think this solution will not give you what you're looking for unless there will only ever be a single invoice under each opportunity.

```
Id key = '006G000000TZ2f9IAD';

// create the map to hold the opportunity id and the name of the invoice record
Map<Id, String> invoicesMap = new Map<Id, String>();

// query for the invoices of this opportunity
List<Invoice1__c> invoiceList = [SELECT Opportunity__c
                                    , Name
                                FROM Invoice1__c
                                WHERE Opportunity__c = :key];

// populate the map
for (Invoice1__c invoice : invoiceList) {

    // add the entry to the map, capture any old value for this key
    String previousValue = (String)invoicesMap.put(invoice.Opportunity__c, invoice.Name);

    // see if we overwrote anything
    if (previousValue != null || previousValue != '') {
        system.debug('The map already contained a value with this key: [' + invoice.Opportunity__c + ' : ' + previousValue + ']');
    }
}

// as you've got it written above, using a single Opportunity ID in the where clause
// will cause the map to only ever have one entry and one invoice name in it

system.debug('Created Map. Number of Invoice names mapped=' + invoicesMap.size()); // will always be 1
system.debug('InvoicesMap.Get=' + invoicesMap.get(key)); // will always be the last item in the loop above
```